# Google Cloud: prevent users from syncing to other instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I want an instance having a local user with the purpose of running and owning a service on that instance. I have tried creating it with a simple

```
adduser <username>
```

as well as following,
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only, according to the following

```
instance_a='<instance_a>'

ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "test_ssh_key"
gcloud compute instances add-metadata $instance_a --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=test_ssh_key.pub
gcloud compute ssh $instance_a --ssh-key-file='test_ssh_key'
```

However, in both cases, the created user is automatically synced to all other running instance in the project. Also, in the second case, I'm able to ssh into a second instance even though the documentation says it's for a single instance, despite the ssh key not showing up with

```
gcloud compute instances describe $instance_a
```

Note that ssh with the newly created key works using both gcloud compute ssh and regular ssh.

Does anyone know how to properly either create a truly local user on an instance or alternatively turn off the service syncing users having no ssh login?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I allow access to GCE to only the dev that created the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795302/how-do-i-allow-access-to-gce-to-only-the-dev-that-created-the-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this using Google managed SSH keys (when you use gcloud compute ssh)
Using instance level SSH will work (as you are doing), just make sure to remove any project level metadata for the same user.

Also make sure the new user is completely limited by 
A) Make sure the user does not have IAM permissions to use google managed SSH
B) Limit the scopes of the default service account on the instance to ensure users are not using that to bypass the security measures you have in place.