# How do I allow access to GCE to only the dev that created the server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Right now everyone can access absolutely any server in GCE so long as they have GCE access. The `gcloud comput ssh` command can ssh into any server.

How do I make sure that only the person that created the server has access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to implement access control to instances based on [GCE IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam) via [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access):

> After you [enable OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin) on one or more instances in your project,
>   those instances accept connections only from user accounts who have
>   the necessary IAM roles in your project or organization:
>
> As an example, you might grant instance access to your users with the
>   following process:
>
> 1. [Grant the necessary instance access roles](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org#grant-access) to the user. Users must have the following roles:
>
>    - The `iam.serviceAccountUser` role.
>    - One of the following login roles:
>
>      - The `compute.osLogin` role, which does not grant administrator permissions
>      - The `compute.osAdminLogin` role, which grants administrator permissions

But note that not all GCE image families have OS Login support:

> The following image families do not yet support OS Login:
>
> - All project coreos-cloud (CoreOS) image families
> - Project suse-cloud (SLES) image family sles-11
> - All Windows Server and SQL Server image families

Comment: Alternatively, you can manage instance access manually by adding and removing [SSH keys in metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys).